# How to replace twentytwenty wordpress modal search from header with products search

Tags: wordpress, twentytwenty

Here is the code from template-parts/modal-search.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Displays the search icon and modal
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Twenty
 * @since Twenty Twenty 1.0
 */

?>
<div class="search-modal cover-modal header-footer-group" data-modal-target-string=".search-modal">

    <div class="search-modal-inner modal-inner">

        <div class="section-inner">

            <?php
            get_search_form(
                array(
                    'label' => __( 'Search for:', 'twentytwenty' ),
                )
            );
            ?>

            <button class="toggle search-untoggle close-search-toggle fill-children-current-color" data-toggle-target=".search-modal" data-toggle-body-class="showing-search-modal" data-set-focus=".search-modal .search-field" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Close search', 'twentytwenty' ); ?></span>
                <?php twentytwenty_the_theme_svg( 'cross' ); ?>
            </button><!-- .search-toggle -->

        </div><!-- .section-inner -->

    </div><!-- .search-modal-inner -->

</div><!-- .menu-modal -->
```

And here is an image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWInv.png)

I want to change this to search for products since this is an online store instead of using wordpress post search.

Answer (score 0):

replace get_search_form with get_product_search_form